# all subsets of lists in KDB+

Tags: subset, combinations, permutation, kdb

I am new to KDB. I have a table in following format:

```
id        date  name  order
34  2020.01.20  John     10
23  2020.01.20  John    -20
21  2020.01.20  John     30
43  2020.01.20  John   -400
44  2020.01.20   Dan  -6483  
22  2020.01.20   Dan   8796
```

The sample table can be created as follows:

```
t:([]id:(34, 23, 21, 43, 44, 22); date:(2020.01.20; 2020.01.20; 2020.01.20; 2020.01.20; 2020.01.20; 2020.01.20); name:(`John`John`John`John`Dan`Dan); order:(10, -20, 30, -400, -6483, 8796));
```

I want all the subsets of orders possible for any given `date` and `name` in the below format. Now the `order` column below is sum of `order` value for `id` and all the `ids`.

```
id        date  name  order    ids
34  2020.01.20  John     10     0n
34  2020.01.20  John    -10     23
34  2020.01.20  John     40     21
34  2020.01.20  John   -390     43
34  2020.01.20  John     20     23, 21
34  2020.01.20  John   -360     21, 43
34  2020.01.20  John   -380     23, 21, 43
23  2020.01.20  John    -20     0n
23  2020.01.20  John    -10     34
23  2020.01.20  John     10     21
23  2020.01.20  John   -420     43
23  2020.01.20  John     20     34, 21
23  2020.01.20  John   -390     21, 43
23  2020.01.20  John   -380     34, 21, 43
21  2020.01.20  John     30     0n
21  2020.01.20  John     40     34
21  2020.01.20  John     10     23
21  2020.01.20  John   -370     43
21  2020.01.20  John     20     34, 23
21  2020.01.20  John     20     23, 43
21  2020.01.20  John   -380     34, 23, 43
43  2020.01.20  John   -400     0n
43  2020.01.20  John   -390     34
43  2020.01.20  John   -420     23
43  2020.01.20  John   -370     21
43  2020.01.20  John   -410     34, 23
43  2020.01.20  John   -390     23, 21
43  2020.01.20  John   -380     34, 23, 21
44  2020.01.20   Dan  -6483     0n
44  2020.01.20   Dan   2313     22
22  2020.01.20   Dan   8796     0n
22  2020.01.20   Dan   2313     44
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you part of the way, though this approach has an extra combination that you seem to exclude (you can exclude these afterwards if need be):

```
q)comb:{$[type b:(count[a:x except y]-1)(01b cross)/01b;(`long$();a);a where each b]};
q)update sum each order from ungroup ungroup select id,order:(order,/:'order i?comb[i]each i),ids:id i?comb[i]each i by date,name from t
date       name id order ids
---------------------------------
2020.01.20 Dan  44 -6483 `long$()
2020.01.20 Dan  44 2313  ,22
2020.01.20 Dan  22 8796  `long$()
2020.01.20 Dan  22 2313  ,44
2020.01.20 John 34 10    `long$()
2020.01.20 John 34 -390  ,43
2020.01.20 John 34 40    ,21
2020.01.20 John 34 -360  21 43
2020.01.20 John 34 -10   ,23
2020.01.20 John 34 -410  23 43
2020.01.20 John 34 20    23 21
2020.01.20 John 34 -380  23 21 43
2020.01.20 John 23 -20   `long$()
2020.01.20 John 23 -420  ,43
...
```

Comment: This is the better solution. Thanks @terrylynch

Comment: The only problem is it results in duplicate row if  `t` has a unique row, i.e., t has unique date and name. may be adding `distinct` in front of `update` would do.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to append `id` column to `ids` column in final output?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the most optimal solution, but below snippet will do what you are looking for:

```
orderMap: (!) . t`id`order;  
subsets: ungroup
  update ids: {x where each (count[x]-1){x cross 01b}/01b} each ids from 
  select ids: id by name from t;
t: ej[`name;t;subsets];
t: delete from t where id in' ids;
t: update order: order + sum each orderMap@/:ids from  t;
t
```

For consistency, ids column is created as list of integer lists and empty array `` `long$() `` is used instead of `0n`

More detaily:

1. `` orderMap: (!) . t`id`order `` gives id-to-order mapping. Here I use assume that `id`s are unique.
2. `subsets` is table of `name`s and `id` subsets assigned to the name. `{(count[x]-1){x cross 01b}/01b}` returns "include" flags which help forming subsets, e.g. `0000b, 1000b, 0100b, ...`. Could be done more efficiently with integers binary representation.
3. `` ej[`name;t;subsets] `` - joins original table with id subsets by name.
4. `delete from t where id in' ids` deletes rows where `id` is included into `ids` subset.
5. `update order: order + sum each orderMap@/:ids from  t` sums up order of `id` and `ids`' subset by using `orderMap`

Comment: It breaks up if `t` has a unique entry, i.e., if date and name are unique.